# On the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

How would one go to prove that

$$\gamma = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$

where $\gamma$ stands for the Euler - Mascheroni constant and $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is the floor function?

Honestly , I have no idea how to tackle it.

Comment: This statement cannot be proved, but only disproved! As fastly shown in my solution, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\gamma+\log(2)-5/4.$$

Comment: You have that $$\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{10000} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}\approx 0.520362837027662078369$$ and $$\gamma \approx 0.57721566490153286061.$$ Do you see the difference?

Comment: (-1) By keeping that wrong result you spread confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Simple creative telescoping sums reveal
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1} \frac{\left \lfloor \log_2 n \right \rfloor}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\sum_{n=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1} \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}+\lim_{n\to\infty}(\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n\left((k+1) \psi(2^{k+1})-k\psi(2^{k})\right)}_{\text{telescoping sum}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n\left(k\psi(2^{k+1})-(k+1)\psi(2^{k+2})\right)}_{\text{telescoping sum}}$$
$$+\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n(\psi(2^{k+2})-\psi(2^{k+1}))}_{\text{telescoping sum}})$$
$$=\gamma+\log(2)-5/4.$$

Q.E.D.

**Reference**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm pretty sire the result is the one I gave ! There is a theorem on that. Would you mind checking your computations again?

Comment: @Tolaso my calculations are perfect. It's simple to numerically compare the partial sum with, say, the first 1000 terms, to the closed-form I gave. Also, could you check your calculations again?